# Output all language strings in Revel?

Tags: go, revel

I'm developing an API Server in Go and the server (at the moment) handles all translations for clients. When an API client fetches particular data it also asks for the translations that are available for the given section.

Ideally I want to have the following folder structure:

```
/messages
  /home.en
  /home.fr
  /home.sv
  /news.en
  /news.fr
  /news.sv
```

Where `news` and `home` are distinct modules.

Now the question I have for Revel is is it possible to fetch ALL language strings for a given module and given locale? For example pull all home strings for en-US.

EDIT:

I would like the output (something I can return to the client) a key:value string of translations.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: are you storing all of en-US, en-UK, en-AU etc in the `home.en` or `news.en` folders? Or are they going to be separated into folders such as `home.en-US` and `home.en-UK`? Just trying to determine if you could just open all files from `fmt.Sprintf("/messages/%s.%s", module, locale)`.

Comment: Well, per Revel suggestion each locale would have a different section within the same file. Presently I don't anticipate there being many differences just things like "zip code" vs "postal code". So I can't warrant a need for a separate file per locale. If that answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that revel uses messaged based translation (just like gettext does), so you need
the original string to get the translation. These strings are stored in Config objects, 
which are themselves stored in `messages` of [i18n.go](https://github.com/robfig/revel/blob/master/i18n.go#L24), sorted by language.

As you can see, this mapping is not exported, so you can't access it. The best way
to fix this is to write a function for what you want (getting the config by supplying a language)
**or** exporting one of the existing functions and create a pull request for revel.

You may workaround this by copying the code of [`loadMessageFile`](https://github.com/robfig/revel/blob/master/i18n.go#L98) or by forking your version
of revel and exporting `loadMessageFile` or `parseMessagesFile`. This also is a great opportunity
to create a pull request.

Note that the localizations are stored in a INI file format parsed by [`robfig/config`](https://github.com/robfig/config), 
so manually parsing is also an option (although not recommended).